# ERROR: Wheel 'tensorflow' located at /tmp/pip-unpack-pgidfwwg/tensorflow-2.11.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl is invalid

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, machine-learning, deep-learning, pip

I'm trying to install tensorflow, and i get this error every time:

```
pip install tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Downloading tensorflow-2.11.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (588.3 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╺━━━━━━━━━ 434.8/588.3 MB 393.6 kB/s eta 0:06:30
ERROR: Wheel 'tensorflow' located at /tmp/pip-unpack-pgidfwwg/tensorflow-2.11.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl is invalid.
```

i tried older version but still got the same error.

```
pip install tensorflow==2.10.0
```

I have ryzen asus laptop with amd radeon graphics running 64-bit ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS

Comment: Hi @AlirezaSoleimanian, please let us know the versions of pip and python you are using so that we can assist you better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use pip install tensorflow-gpu -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).